# Using SELECT with INNER JOIN and WHILE

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select, inner-join

I want to understand it on this "simple" query example. 
I wanto to view dates and order IDs with the highest order value (profit) in each quarter of 1997. I can write something like this.

```
SELECT o.OrderDate, o.OrderID, DATEPART(QUARTER, o.OrderDate)
FROM Orders o INNER JOIN (SELECT...)
WHERE YEAR(o.OrderDate) = '1997'
GROUP BY o.OrderDate, o.OrderID;
```

`OrderDetails` contains order value (price). Catch is i don't want to view the value, so i need to use SELECT with INNER JOIN or WHILE (probably INNER JOIN in this case). I have tried multiple solutions and it shows more than 800 rows, when it should only return 4 rows. There is also a problem that `GROUP BY` won't really work as expected with OrderDate.

I expect results like this:

```
Order date | OrderID | Quarter
05.02.1997 | 173412  | 1
05.04.1997 | 421552  | 2
12.07.1997 | 735245  | 3
24.12.1997 | 825425  | 4
```

Query with some small explanation will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Then group by the data by DATEPART(QUARTER, o.OrderDate)

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result as tabular text (not image) ... what do  you mean with  "with the highest value " ..?? which?  value ??

Comment: Why `GROUP BY` when no aggregate functions are involved? Why join when you only select columns from one of the tables?

Comment: Based on what you wrote, your query is already logically flawed. You join to OrderDetails yet you refer to none of the columns in your query (excluding the join). Use of a <group by> clause without an aggregate is also a clue that you are attempting to cover up a logic flaw. Lastly, you use the term "highest value" but you do not define what this means. So the first step is to define that and, if needed, the logic you need to compute it. Without that, there is no point to attempt to write additional logic that is based on this value.

Comment: *Highest value*  of what? Have a look at `row_number` or `rank`

Comment: @jarlh OrderDetails contains order value (price). It's not included because i'm asking how to include it. And without `GROUP BY` query won't launch - it requires `GROUP BY`.

Comment: You are selecting no columns from `od`, so why bother with the `join`?

Comment: @Corporal203 Why won't query launch without `GROUP BY`?  There's no aggregation in your query, unless it's not the full query.

Comment: @Eric when i remove anything from `GROUP BY` it throws error. `Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: OK you have an error, so give your code & the error. Please clarify ia edits, not comments. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular formatted initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want some kind of Windowed Aggregate:

```
with cte as
 (
   SELECT *,
      -- "highest value" per quarter
      max(whatever)
      over (partition by DATEPART(QUARTER, o.OrderDate)) as max_value
   FROM OrderDetails od INNER JOIN Orders o ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID
   WHERE YEAR(o.OrderDate) = '1997'
 ) 
select distinct
   o.OrderDate, o.OrderID, DATEPART(QUARTER, o.OrderDate)
from cte
-- current value = highest value of the quarter 
where whatever = max_value
```

This will return more than a single row per quarter if multiple rows with the same *highest value* exist. If you just want a single row you must switch to `row_number`

```
with cte as
 (
   SELECT *,
      -- "highest value" per quarter = row_number 1
      row_number()
      over (partition by DATEPART(QUARTER, o.OrderDate)
            order by whatever desc) as rn
   FROM OrderDetails od INNER JOIN Orders o ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID
   WHERE YEAR(o.OrderDate) = '1997'
 ) 
select o.OrderDate, o.OrderID, DATEPART(QUARTER, o.OrderDate)
from cte
-- "highest value" per quarter = row_number 1
where rn = 1
```

If you insist upon using old SQL, you can do the same without using Windowed Aggregates (but way more complex and probably way less efficient):

```
with cte as
 ( -- prepare the base data to avoid writing the same join/where twice
   SELECT o.OrderDate, o.OrderID, DATEPART(QUARTER, o.OrderDate) as q, whatever
   FROM OrderDetails od INNER JOIN Orders o
     ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID
   WHERE YEAR(o.OrderDate) = '1997'
 )
SELECT DISTINCT t1.OrderDate, t1.OrderID, t1.q
FROM cte
join 
 ( 
   select q, 
      -- "highest value" per quarter
      max(whatever) as max_value
   from cte
   group by q
 ) as maxperq
on cte.q = maxperq.q  -- same quarter
and cte.whatever = maxperq.whatever -- highest value of the quarter
```

Comment: Here you are using different construction. I want to solve this example using this specific method to understand the method. But i appreciate the help.

Comment: @Corporal203: I added an old-style query, but you shouldn't use it :-)

Comment: @Corporal203 -- what is wrong with using this way to solve it -- this is the right way to do it -- there is no other code that makes this "simple"

Comment: @Hogan: My 1st query using Windowed Aggregates is much simpler than the 2nd using max+join back

Comment: Ok, i suppose this is what i wanted. I will analyze it. Thanks for help.